# Arithmetic with variables not working

Tags: javascript, string, variables, numbers, integer

For some reason, the arithmetic in the function `updateScore(result)` doesn't work properly (the function is called later on in the code). `wins`, `ties` and `losses` are printed as they should, but `lives` is printed as *NaN*. I know what *NaN* means. I've also identified that the variables, for some reason or other, are created as strings. What appears strange to me, is that it's working for four out of five variables. There's no consistency. I've tried some number conversions using `Number(lives)`, but that doesn't work either. Any suggestions to how I can ensure that the variables are created as numbers, and aritmethic operations will work?

```
var wins = 0,
    ties = 0,
    losses = 0,
    lives = 5,
    previouscpuChoice = 0;

$("#startknapp").click(function(){
    var spiller = prompt("Hva heter du?");
    $("#userSelect").html(userMenu);
    $("#result").html("<h4>Velg figur, " + spiller + "</h4>");
    $("#status").html('<h4>Liv: <span id="life">' +lives+ '</span> - Seire: <span id="win">' + wins + '</span> - Uavgjort: <span id="tie">' + ties + '</span> - Tap: <span id="lose">' + losses + '</span>');
    console.log(typeof "lives");
    console.log(typeof "wins");
    });

function updateScore(result) {
    tie = document.getElementById("tie");
    win = document.getElementById("win");
    lose = document.getElementById("lose");
    lives = document.getElementById("life");
    console.log(typeof "wins");
    var imgSrc = "images/" + userChoice + "-" + result + ".png";

    if (result === "tie") {
    ties = ties + 1;
    tie.innerHTML = ties;
    $('.result-img').attr('src', 'images/tie.png');
    }

    if (result === "vant") {
    wins++;
    $('.result-img').attr('src', imgSrc);
    }

    if (result === "tapte") {
    losses++;
    lives--;
    lose.innerHTML = losses;
    life.innerHTML = lives;
    $('.result-img').attr('src', imgSrc);
    }
};
```

Comment: _getElementById_ returns **DOM element**, not input's value. I would advise you to not write on vanilla JS at the moment, use JS library like jQuery instead.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?

```
var tie = parseInt(document.getElementById("tie").value);
```

Your current code:

```
document.getElementById("tie")
```

retrieves the DOM element rather than the value of the input. so you need to use `.value` and then you parse it as an integer as the inputs value is likely a string representation of the number you want rather than an integer value.

Comment: I was considering that myself at first, and I'll try it and provide feedback. What struck me as strange however, was that the variables are identified as strings when I print them to the console directly after assigning them.

Comment: When you assigned the variables at the top or when you assigned them with UpdateScore? The "+" operator in JS is kind of weird. If you have a string + a number then it will concatenate rather than throwing an error or adding them together. Any of the other operators will conver it to a number for example if your string was called x and you did x*1 then it would convert it to a number and multiply it by 1 (giving you the same value).

Comment: Ah I think I misunderstood. You mean when you ran `console.log(typeof "lives");` it returned string? In this case it is because you're checking what type "lives" is, which is a string. You want the typeof the variable `lives` so you should not use the speech marks like so: `console.log(typeof lives);`. This will check the typeof the variable rather than the string you've given it.

Comment: After applying these changes, it no longer ends as *NaN*. However, none of the arithmetic operations seem to work when `updateScore` is called. Firefox shows no errors, but Chrome shows: _Cannot read property 'value' of null_ in the console. But only for `lives`, not for the others. And, when changing the console.log statement, it no longer prints anything.

Comment: Could you add your HTML to the question as well? It might be that your selector for the `lives` element is incorrect. This is why you are getting null, the selector isn't able to 'select' anything

Comment: The relevant HTML is just `<div class="row" id="status"></div>`. The relevant HTML is created by JS; `$("#status").html('<h4>Liv: <span id="life">' +lives+ '</span> - Seire: <span id="win">' + wins + '</span> - Uavgjort: <span id="tie">' + ties + '</span> - Tap: <span id="lose">' + losses + '</span>');`. That's why I was using `document.getElementById` rather than its JQuery equivalent.

Comment: You can also check it here: [link](http://kolonnekjoring.no/roswell/ncb/index_new.html).

Comment: You are trying to select with `document.getElementById("lives").value` but the id of your span is `life`. Try `document.getElementById("life").value`

Answer (score 1):

After pondering, I figured it's okay if the variables are strings, and looked at the code from a different perspective. And what do you know, it was a simple bug.

```
$("#startknapp").click(function(){
    var spiller = prompt("Hva heter du?");
    $("#userSelect").html(userMenu);
    $("#result").html("<h4>Velg figur, " + spiller + "</h4>");
    $("#status").html('<h4>Liv: <span id="life">' +lives+ '</span> - Seire: <span id="win">' + wins + '</span> - Uavgjort: <span id="tie">' + ties + '</span> - Tap: <span id="lose">' + losses + '</span>');
    console.log(typeof "lives");
    console.log(typeof "wins");
    });

function updateScore(result) {
    tie = document.getElementById("tie");
    win = document.getElementById("win");
    lose = document.getElementById("lose");
    life = document.getElementById("life");
```

Originally the last line of updateScore(result) was:

```
    lives = document.getElementById("life");
```

As a result two variables were mixed (the local one for the function (life) and the global one (lives). So in the end it was a typo. However, I'm still intrigued by the fact that a variable can be a string, and the value contained within an integer.

Comment: Glad you managed to resolve it. I don't know if you figured it out yourself or looked at my last comment but I hope what I said was helpful. Javascript variables aren't really that type safe which can make arithmetic operations like `+` give you interesting results that can be infuriating to debug.

Comment: Of course your comments helped. When I tried the solution you suggested, I found that none of the arithmetic worked. Hence, it had to be a problem related to the way I assigned the variable. So you've been of good help to me. Now, all I have to do is figure out a good game loop.